# I can solve this problem using a computationally heuristic method, but not mathematically

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I have this following problem: "I plan to put my photos into an album with the same number of photos on each page. If I put 6 to a page, there are 4 left over, I put 7 to a page, there are 5 left over. If I put 8 to a page, there are 6 left over. What is the smallest number of photos that I could have??"

I used loops in a computer program to test integers, and I got 502 photos. Here is my system of linear equations:

```
6x_1 + 4 = y
7x_2 + 5 = y
8x_3 + 6 = y
```

"y" being the total number of photos, and x_1, x_2, and x_3 being the number of pages in each case. The system has infinite solutions, but I don't know how to derive 502 algebraically. I would greatly appreciate to please understand the logic (hint) Thank you!

EDIT: After some research, it seems to be a diophantine equation. I'm studying the method right now.

Comment: @NoChance He meant 6 per page. 503 mod 6=4, 502 mod 7 =5, 502 mod 8 =6.

Comment: @QuoteDave, I see now. Thanks. However, it looks like 2 variables are in play, the number of photos (that he wants min.) and the number of pages. Still vague!

Comment: I doesn't seem vague to me. It's a system of congruences, that can be solved using the Chinese Remainder Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of photos. The given conditions are that $n \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$, $n \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$, and $n \equiv 6 \pmod{8}.$ Observe that these conditions are equivalent to $n+2$ being divisible by $6$, $7$, and $8$, which is equivalent to $n+2$ being divisible by $\operatorname{lcm}(6,7,8) = 168$. So the smallest solution is $n = 166$ (and in general the solutions are $166 + 168k$ for all nonnegative integers $k$).

Without the above observation about $n+2$, you could also apply the Chinese remainder theorem to $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, $n \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$, and $n \equiv 6 \pmod{8}$, which gives you an algorithm to obtain the unique solution mod $168$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the Chinese remainder theorem, but not your first solution. Could you please elaborate? Thank you!